# Encrypted External Harddrive

Tags: windows, encryption, external

I am trying to access an external hard drive which I filled with files and encrypted from my computer. After I filled it I formatted everything on my local hard drive so even though it is the same machine, none of the same users exist. Both the old and current OS are Windows 10.

I can see the files but I cannot open them, so it seems like the files are encrypted, rather than the whole external drive. When I click on the properties I see my old user at old domain, but I cannot add the current user. I don't have read/write permissions. This makes sense because I wouldn't want anyone to just add their user an be able to see my stuff.

The frustrating thing is that I know the password I used to encrypt it, but I can't find anywhere to enter my password so it doesn't seem to matter that I haven't forgotten it.

Can anyone please advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What did you use to encrypt it? Obviously, it wasn't BitLocker, because then the file system (i.e., file names) would not be visible. Your best bet is to try to see if there's a back-door to the encryption you used, or better yet, see if there's a security hole in it. Considering it's not BitLocker, you at least have a reasonable hope of that.

However, what you want to do is *precisely* what encryption exists to prevent, i.e., if you could do it, it would completely defeat the purpose of encrypting the files in the first place. I mean, what if rather than you, a bad guy found your drive and wanted to do the same thing? If it were possible *at all*, then there would be no point in encrypting in the first place.

Finally, a third option would be to see if anyone has built a dictionary-attack brute-force password crack tool for the encryption tool you used. Since I don't know what you used to encrypt it, I don't know if such a tool exists, but if you know how the encryption works, and how the keys are generated from the passwords, theoretically one could write one themselves.